# ¿Por qué no se pasa el valor del div al input? JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Estoy intentando hacer a través del siguiente código que al hacer click en `<div id="cont-1">` el valor que se encuentra alojado en el mismo pase a un input con `id=input`, el problema es que al hacer click no "pasa" el valor del div al input.

```
$('.cont-1').click(function(){

document.getElementById('input').innerHTML = $('#cont-1').text();
```

Código actualizado por la propuesta de David:

```
    $('.cont-1').click(function(){

    $('#input').value($('#cont-1').text());


});
```

Error:

> core-login.js:85 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).value is not a function
> at HTMLDivElement. (core-login.js:85:17)
> at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2:43064)
> at v.handle (jquery.min.js:2:41048)

Comment: Ya que estas usando jquery, has probado usar jquery para pasarle el valor? $('#input').value($('#cont-1').text())

Comment: Hola @David081 he probado pero en la consola no me reconoce el ".value" como función, añado el error a la publicación

Comment: Sustituye `.value()` por `.val()`, es decir `$('#input').val($('#cont-1').text());`

Comment: @SrMiamibeach genial, ha funcionado; si quieres pon una respuesta que te la marco cómo válida

Comment: Mi error, .val() es la funcion de jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema de la solución del comentario de @David081 es que la función `.value()` no existe, tienes que sustituirla por `.val()`

**Solución:**

```
$('#input').val($('#cont-1').text());
```

**Actualización**

Para sumar el valor del div al valor ya existente del input primero tendrías que guardar el valor del input y luego añadir al input su valor y el del div.

**Solución**

```
$('.cont-1').click(function(){
 let input = $('#input').val();
 $('#input').val(input + $('#cont-1').text());
});
```

Comment: Probándolo me he dado cuenta de que reemplaza el valor existente del input por el del div, habría alguna manera de que en vez de que se reemplazara se "sumara" al existente? Para ponerte en contexto, quiero hacer una especie de teclado virtual.

Comment: es decir el texto que hay en el input no se borre no?

Comment: Sí, que sea acumulativo

Comment: En breve lo compruebo y te digo, gracias de antemano